# Android MediaRecorder save file path

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app using the MediaRecorder().
Currently, I am storing the recording file at the default app directory. This is done using

Filename is set by:

```java
    private fun confirmEditText(v: TextView, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            if (v.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Empty File Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                fileName = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)?.absolutePath + "/" + v.text.toString() + ".wav"
                //fileName = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath + "/" + v.text.toString() + ".wav"
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

And then save it like so

```
try {
    val values = ContentValues(2)
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
    mediaRecorder?.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.UNPROCESSED)
    mediaRecorder?.setOutputFormat(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
    mediaRecorder?.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
    mediaRecorder?.setOutputFile(fileName)
    mediaRecorder?.prepare()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

I wish to default all the file to the Music folder that is default on Android. How can I do so?

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, keeping in account scoped storage changes on Android 10 as well

```
val externalStorageUri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        } else {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        }

val dirDest = File(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC,
            context.getString(R.string.app_name)
        )

val date = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val fileName = "$date.wav"

val newAudio = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "$dirDest${File.separator}")

            }

val fileUri = context.contentResolver.insert(externalStorageUri, newAudio)
```

And once you have the `fileUri` you can easily make a `File` object out of it and then use it in `setOutputFile`

And now as far as the permissions are concerned, the following should do, since on Android Q+ you won't need explicit permission to access publicly available directories on android like `DOCUMENTS`,`AUDIO`, `PICTURES` etc

```
<uses-permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android:maxSdkVersion=28/>
```

Comment: `And once you have the fileUri you can easily make a File object out of it` Well is that true? But if true then using the media store first makes no sense as then you could directly build up that path yourself. `new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), filename);`

Comment: We need something like `mediaRecorder?.setOutputUri(fileUri)`.

Comment: `you won't permission to access publicly available directories on android` Well you have access to those. And `Music` is a public directory too.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I dont quite get the part on new File and mediaRecorder?.setOutputUri(fileUri). What do i need to add?

Comment: @blackapps `new File(Uri)` can give a file which can be used to `setOutputFile`. I will rely on this code because it will make sure that a file at this uri exists, ofcourse your method is corrected too but I'm myself not sure about the `getExternalStorageDirectory` and its other variants available in the `Context` class

Comment: Also you're correct about the permission part, maybe there was a typo there

Comment: `new File(Uri) can give a file ` Dont believe so. Please give an examle of the value of `new File(Uri).getAbsolutePath() `. Post the value of the used uri too: `uri.toString()`